# Bmesh code from 3D object

Tags: python, bmesh

Does anyone know of an addon or script that can take a 3D object that was modeled in Blender and turn it into Bmesh based code?
Would be super handy.

I can't seem to find anything, but hopefully one of you fine folk will know of something.

Comment: In the Scripting workspace under *Templates > Python* there are two templates, *Bmesh Simple* and *Bmesh Editmode*. You can also check [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html) out for examples of how to do Bmesh operations.

Comment: Thanks @Jakemoyo, my proficancy with bmesh is fairly good, what I'm looking for is an addon that takes a 3D object and spits out bmesh based code that would build the object, so I can model something and not have to write the code for it... Get tedious writing 3 hours of code for something that takes 5 mins to model XD

Answer (score 0):

I found something good enough from here:
https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-save-mesh-data-to-text/

It takes the active object and spits out the verticies and faces that can then be used with `from_pydata(verts, [], faces)` to create that object.

This is new to me and wanted to share.

Comment: That's good, I would recommend writing it to a [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) file, that way when you read it in, it can already be in dictionary format.